# How to fetch data from 2nd sheet in Google SpreadSheets

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api

Hi I am referring [this blog](http://mscodingblog.blogspot.in/2016/11/how-to-read-google-spreadsheet-using.html) for fetching data from google spreadsheets ,i am able to get data from first sheet using the code mentioned in the article ,but how to fetch data from **2nd Sheet in Same SpreadSheet**.

I have not included any code because i am using the same code which is there in the blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Pass the Range as Follows in the Main Method

Original Code

```
var range = "A:B";
```

change it to

```
 var range = "SecondSheetName!A:B";
```